# ListView item SelectionChanged does not trigger on unselect, using WPF with MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a `ListView` which correctly sends the selected items on `SelectionChanged` to my `ViewModel`. When an item or items are selected, the `SelectionChanged` property sends the selected items. But when unselecting an item or several items, it does not trigger the `SelectionChanged` property.

Here is what I have done:

**XAML**

```
<ListView 
  x:Name="myListView"
  SelectionMode="Extended">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GetSelectedItemsCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myListView, Path=SelectedItems}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Nombre" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Dirección" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FilePath}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

**ViewModel**

```
private ObservableCollection<FileItem> _selectedItems = new ObservableCollection<FileItem>();

public ObservableCollection<FileItem> SelectedItems
{
   get { return _selectedItems; }
   set { SetProperty(ref _selectedItems, value); }
}
private DelegateCommand<ObservableCollection<Object>> _getSelectedItems;

public DelegateCommand<ObservableCollection<Object>> GetSelectedItemsCommand =>
    _getSelectedItems ?? (_getSelectedItems = new DelegateCommand<ObservableCollection<Object>>(ExecuteGetSelectedItems));

private void ExecuteGetSelectedItems(ObservableCollection<Object> fileItems)
{
    foreach (var file in fileItems)
    {
        FileItem fileItem = (FileItem)file;
        if (fileItem != null && !SelectedItems.Contains(file))
        {
            SelectedItems.Add(fileItem);
        }
    }
}
```

I need a way to get the unselected items because the `SelectionChanged` property is not working on unselect.

Comment: If you would pass the arguments from the SelecitonChange and not overwrite them with your collection (which makes not so much sense in current scenario) the default argument is System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs and it contains the Added to the collection items (what you are sending now) as well as removed from the collection items (what you are looking for). all you need is relpace  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myListView, Path=SelectedItems}" with PassEventArgsToCommand="True" and change delegate command type

Comment: Why not just bind isselected to a property in the item viewmodel?

Answer (score 0):

You should not deal with UI event data in the view model. `Interaction` behaviors usually lead to code smells that violate the MVVM design rules. It's just a superfluous helper.
The solution is simple: handle the `SelectionChanged` event and use the event data to get selected and unselected items. From here you have multiple good solutions:

1. Pass the data directly to the view model class instance by invoking API methods (view model type is no longer anonymous)
2. Invoke an `ICommand` implementation that is bound to the current element and pass data as command arguments
3. Update local dependency properties that are bound to the data source

The following example uses an attached property to allow the registration of an `ICommand` that will be invoked on `Selector.SelectionChanged`.
Using an attached property for this maximizes the flexibility as it enables each `SelctionChanged` source element to define its own `ICommand` without having to implement a new dependency property for each:

**DataChanges.cs**
Data argument used to exchange data with the view model. This is optional. It only makes data handling more convenient.

```cs
class DataChanges<TItem>
{
  public DataChanges(TItem oldValue, TItem newValue)
  {
    this.OldValue = oldValue;
    this.NewValue = newItems;
  }

  public TItem NewValue { get; }
  public TItem OldValue { get; }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```cs
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public DelegateCommand<DataChanges<IEnumerable<FileItem>>> ProcessSelectedItemsCommand { get; }
    = new DelegateCommand<DataChanges<IEnumerable<FileItem>>>(ExecuteProcessSelectedItemsCommand));

  private void ExecuteProcessSelectedItemsCommand(DataChanges<IEnumerable<FileItem>> dataChanges)
  {
    RemoveUnselectedFileItems(dataChanges.OldValue);
    AddSelectedFileItems(dataChanges.NewValue);
  }

  private void AddSelectedFileItems(IEnumerable<FileItem> itemsToAdd)
  {
    // Use LINQ to filter duplicates
    var newItemsExcludingExistingItems = itemsToAdd.Except(this.SelectedItems);
    foreach (FileItem newFileItem in newItemsExcludingExistingItems)
    {
      this.SelectedItems.Add(newFileItem);
    }
  }

  private void RemoveUnselectedFileItems(IEnumerable<FileItem> itemsToRemove)
  {
    foreach (FileItem oldFileItem in itemsToRemove)
    {
      this.SelectedItems.Remove(oldFileItem);
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static void SetFileItemsChangedCommande(UIElement attachingElement, ICommand value)
    => attachingElement.SetValue(FileItemsChangedCommandProperty, value);

  public static ICommand GetFileItemsChangedCommande(UIElement attachingElement)
    => return (ICommand)attachingElement.GetValue(FileItemsChangedCommandProperty);

  public static readonly DependencyProperty FileItemsChangedCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "FileItemsChangedCommand",
    typeof(ICommand),
    typeof(MainWindow),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
  }

  private void OnFileItemsSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var sourceElement = (UIElement)sender;
    ICommand command = GetFileItemsChangedCommand(sourceElement);

    IEnumerable<FileItem> oldFileItems = e.RemovedItems.Cast<FileItem>();
    IEnumerable<FileItem> newFileItems = e.AddedItems.Cast<FileItem>();
    var commandArgument = new DataChanges<IEnumerable<FileItem>>(oldFileItems, newFileItems);
    if (command?.CanExecute(commandArgument) ?? false)
    {
      command. Execute(commandArgument);
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <ListBox MainWindow.FileItemsChangedCommand="{Binding ProcessSelectedItemsCommand}"
           SelectionChanged="OnFileItemsSelectionChanged" />
</Window>
```